# jQuery Datatables in ASP.NET MVC applications

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm trying to fetch my users list data into jQuery Datatable, but instead of data getting populated in my Datatable, it just returns a raw JSON format page with my data.

I have searched all over the internet mostly what is written in their solution I'm applying the same technique.

Here is my ASP.NET MVC action method:

```
[Route("Admin/Users")]
public ActionResult GetAllUsers()
{
    List<UsersModel> datas = new List<UsersModel>();
    Dt = _helper.GetAllUsers();

    if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in Dt.Rows)
        {
            UsersModel users = new UsersModel
            {
                UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["USERID"]),
                UserName = dr["USERNAME"].ToString(),
                Password = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString(),
                SchoolCode = dr["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString(),
                BranchCode = dr["MAINACCOUNTID"].ToString(),
                IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ISACTIVE"])
            };
            datas.Add(users);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "No Users Found";
    }

    return Json(new { data = datas }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) ;
}
```

Here is my jQuery Datatable being used in view `GetAllUsers.cshtml`:

```
@model SiteAdministrator1._1._0.Models.UsersModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetAllUsers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_adminLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>GetAllUsers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="usersList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                UserID
            </th>
            <th>
                UserName
            </th>
            <th>
                Password
            </th>
            <th>
                SchoolCode
            </th>
            <th>
                BranchCode
            </th>
            <th>
                IsActive
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>

</table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#usersList').Datatable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetAllUsers", "Admin")",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "UserID" },
                    { "data": "UserName" },
                    { "data": "Password" },
                    { "data": "SchoolCode" },
                    { "data": "BranchCode" },
                    { "data": "IsActive" },

                    // Add other columns as per your model
                ]
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Note:**

1. I have integrated all the jQuery and Datatable libraries.
2. I have checked my Datatable connections, i.e. connection string) and queries written in the stored procedures
3. I have used debugger to see if I am able to fetch the data from the databases and it works perfectly fine
4. I am doing all this database fetching through ADO.NET (no entity data model, no Entity Framework)
5. If I just fetch it in a list template bind my model it works fine and shows the data in ASP.NET MVC list template

Comment: Please help me with a solution to get it populated in jquery Datatable !

Comment: The action method shown is called “GetAllUsers”, but in the DataTables AJAX settings you specified a method called “GetAllUser”.  But the view shown is called “GetAllUsers”.  Did you just confuse yourself with similarly named methods?  Which action method returns this view?  What URL are you using to try and reach this view?

Comment: That's just a spelling mistake I did while posting my question.I would genuinely appericiate the guidance what could I check or rectify to get my desired solution

Comment: Then where is the second “GetAllUsers” action method?  The one which returns this view?  It still sounds like you’re just confused between which method you’re trying to call.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was asking like how and what do I work on the second "GetAllUsers" action method like make a HTTP Post method but how do I operate the ajax call in it

Comment: Sir, I'm very new to MVC and I don't have that much hands on expertise on this, that'sy I'm asking for help

Comment: Well, you’re showing a view.  But how do you get to that view?  Before trying to incorporate anything like DataTables or any other AJAX operations, you need to at least start with the basics.  A controller action that returns a view, and being able to go to that URL and load that view as a page in your browser.  If you haven’t done that yet, you’ll want to start there.

Comment: From the layout page I have created a @Html.Action link that reroutes me to that view but it shows me a Raw JSON page but when in my action I try to return a view it shows that it expects a Model result not a Json result !

Comment: Can you help me with a code written solution or maybe rectify my code that I can come to know what wrong am I doing ? Because I have limited resources to know what I'm doing wrong and I'm not able to know how do I overcome this

Comment: If you only have this one action method then the behavior you’re seeing is correct.  Look at what this action method returns.  It returns JSON.  So you’re getting JSON.  If you want a view, the method needs to return a view.  You’d need a separate method, at a different URL, to return JSON.  Try returning a view from your method and see if it ends up returning a view.

Comment: Okay sir let me try and then I'll get back to you with the response

Comment: thankyou David sir, it worked as you said create an another View and another View that parse the JSON data and populates in the jQuery Datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Route("Admin/Users")]
public ActionResult GetAllUsers() 
{
    var initialData = _helper.GetAllUsers(); 

    var datas = new List<UsersModel>();
    if (initialData.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in initialData.Rows)
        {
            UsersModel user = new UsersModel
            {
                UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["USERID"]),
                UserName = dr["USERNAME"].ToString(),
                Password = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString(),
                SchoolCode = dr["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString(),
                BranchCode = dr["MAINACCOUNTID"].ToString(),
                IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ISACTIVE"])
            };
            datas.Add(user);
        }
    }

    return View("GetAllUsers", datas); }

[Route("Admin/GetAllUsersData")]
public ActionResult GetAllUsersData()
{
    // Fetch and return data in JSON format
    var datas = _helper.GetAllUsers(); 

    return Json(new { data = datas }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this is a better approach as separating for rendering the view and fetching JSON data through different action methods is due to the way web page & client-server interactions function.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("Admin/Users")]
public ActionResult GetAllUsers()
{
    List<UsersModel> datas = new List<UsersModel>();

    try
    {
        Dt = _helper.GetAllUsers();

        if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in Dt.Rows)
            {
                UsersModel users = new UsersModel
                {
                    UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["USERID"]),
                    UserName = dr["USERNAME"].ToString(),
                    Password = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString(),
                    SchoolCode = dr["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString(),
                    BranchCode = dr["MAINACCOUNTID"].ToString(),
                    IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ISACTIVE"])
                };
                datas.Add(users);
            }

            return Json(new { data = datas });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { error = "No Users Found" });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception for troubleshooting.
        return Json(new { error = "An error occurred while fetching users." });
    }
}
```

Can you try it this way too?

Comment: I tried this way the way you have suggested above ,but didn't get the result. then i had to do it this way